# trouble while installing imagemagick on windows 7

Tags: php

My laptop Configuration

- Windows 7 Ultimate 64bit
- php version 5.4.5
- complier MSVC9 (Visual C++ 2008)
- Apache/2.4.3 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1c PHP/5.4.7

I installed ImageMagick-6.7.7-Q16 on laptop
and php_imagick.dll

while i am restart the apache server then error show unable to load dynamic link library php_imagick.dll the specifed module could not be found.
please provide proper solution and link to download the software

Comment: Are you sure about extension=php_imagick.dll is being placed in php.ini?

Comment: yes in php.ini file only

Comment: "Just to make things clear, all the PHP dll files (librarires) are 32 bit, so if your system is 64 bit and you will still need to download and operate 32 bit ImageMagick, Apache, etc." This comment was found on stackoverflow is it true what?